# How to show a gui view from a docker container within a docker-machine on OSX?

Tags: docker, user-interface, x11, docker-machine, xquartz

On my OSX, I can show a gui interface from a docker container successfully with Xqautz as the following command:

```
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --privileged -ti MY_OWN_DOCKER_IMAGE bash
```

However, I would like to put MY_OWN_DOCKER_IMAGE inside a docker-machine(called default) and show the gui interface on my OSX.

My scenario like below:

1. Execute a gui application inside a container running inside default VM.
2. pass GUI view from container to default VM.
3. pass GUI view from default VM to OSX.
4. GUI interface show on my macbook !

I got a question here: how do I set the "-v" and "-e" parameters when I am trying to do "docker run MY_OWN_DOCKER_IMAGE" inside default VM? or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: [X11 forwarding doesn’t work when image runs in docker machine but it works fine if the image is run w/o a docker machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875795/x11-forwarding-doesn-t-work-when-image-runs-in-docker-machine-but-it-works-fine)

-v should be like : -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

but -e DISPLAY should be given an ip(check it from XQuartz with command "xhost")

Now I can show gui interface from container running in a docker machine VM!